# Cant install kubuntu

Tags: unetbootin

My lenovo ideapad came with a dos operating system. I installed ubuntu in it and now i wish to uninstall it and run kubuntu on my laptop. But the laptop doesnt boot from usb anymore.
I made the following changes to the boot menu
    Disabled secured mode
    UEFI boot priority and usb enabled
    In the boot setup, EFI shows ubuntu sshd 8 gb

Downloaded Kubuntu and made the usb bootable with ubuntu on my friends laptop.
I can boot from my pendrive on my friends laptop but not with mine

Comment: Why you are uninstalling the whole system ? If you want Kubuntu, simply install the kde desktop using apt in  your existing Ubuntu.

Comment: Indeed. You don't need to fully uninstall... Kubuntu is just Ubuntu with the KDE desktop environment and a few tweaks. You can install it within ubuntu by doing `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`. When that's done just log out and click the ubuntu icon next to your name and choose kubuntu from the list then log back in.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation for installing kubuntu is to simply install all the kubuntu stuff, and delete all the ubuntu specific stuff with `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop kdeplasma-addons` and `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop`. I'll update this in a few minutes once I know how to change the lockscreen to match, but that should get you pretty close.